# CSS convert percentage to pixel

Tags: css

I know my question may sound odd but I was wondering if there was a way to convert CSS percentage into pixels. My goal with this is to calculate widths and heights with percentage values but not have them change when the screen is resized. If there is another way to achieve my goal I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Depends on your markup i would say. For example if you have a container with a fixed width of 1000px and `position: relative` a child element of this container with let's say `width: 20%` will always have a width of 200px.

Comment: This is true. Would it work to make a container and set width/height in pixels with javascript, then size everything in it with percentage?

Comment: what exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: At the moment, a webpage that, instead of getting smaller on resize, will just be cropped out.

Comment: That sounds like unresponsive default behaviour ;) You should ask a more detailed question, for example show us what you have now and we can help you in a much easier way.

Comment: Well the exact way I want the site to be set up is with a centered content column about 60% of the width of the body, on resize, I want the space around the content column to get smaller while the column itself remains the same size. When the browser is resized smaller than the column, I want it to crop, not scale to fit.

Comment: Well but a relative value for width doesn't make sense in your usecase if you want it to stay fixed. `<div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto">...content...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using javascript.
you get the width of the current width of the element and then set that width to the element.

```
var wid = document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth;
wid+="px"
```

this returns the width in pixels and you append the "px" to the returned numerical value
and then you can set it as below

```
getElementById("mydiv").setAttribute("style",'width:wid');
```

you can fix the width of the document at once in the beggining

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var screenWidth = $(window).width();
   $('html,body').css('width', screenWidth + 'px');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I still wish that there was an easier way to do it more dynamically though :P

Comment: Is it enough dynamic? :p